# mariadb-libs is needed by turnserver

Tags: mysql, centos7, mariadb, video, webrtc

I am trying to install TURN server on centOS7 for one of my webrtc application. This TURN server would be used in a video calling application.
I had followed below steps:

```
yum install -y make gcc cc gcc-c++ wget
yum install -y openssl-devel libevent libevent-devel mysql-devel mysql-server
wget https://github.com/downloads/libevent/libevent/libevent-2.0.21-stable.tar.gz
tar xvfz libevent-2.0.21-stable.tar.gz
cd libevent-2.0.21-stable && ./configure
make && make install && cd ..
wget http://turnserver.open-sys.org/downloads/v4.5.0.7/turnserver-4.5.0.7-CentOS7.4-x86_64.tar.gz
tar -xvzf turnserver-4.5.0.7.tar.gz
cd turnserver-3.2.3.8 && ./configure
make && make install
```

After this , i ran install.sh. I get below error:

```
Package 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.60-1.el7_5.x86_64 is obsoleted by mysql-community-libs-5.6.42-2.el6.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
error: Failed dependencies:
        mariadb-libs is needed by turnserver-4.5.0.7-0.el7.centos.x86_64
```

If i remove mysql and install mariadb, i get other conflict errors.

I have no idea installing this TURN server. Please guide in resolving the error